# Interface class with typecasts to class templates

Tags: c++, templates, casting, abstract-class

I have an interface class (`IBase`) that should contain typecasts to its children. The children are templates:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Derived1 : public IBase
{
private:
    T m_1{};
public:
    Derived1(T arg) : m_1{ arg } {}

    template <typename T>
    operator Derived1<T>() { return *this; }

    template <typename T>
    operator Derived2<T>() { return { m_1 }; }
};

template <typename T>
class Derived2 : public IBase
{
private:
    T m_2{};
public:
    Derived2(T arg) : m_2{ arg } {}

    template <typename T>
    operator Derived1<T>() { return { m_2 }; }

    template <typename T>
    operator Derived2<T>() { return *this; }
};
```

The caller should be able to cast any derived class to another:

```cpp
int main() 
{
    Derived1<double> d1{ 0.0 };
    auto d2{ static_cast<Derived2<int>>(d1) };
}
```

This is where I'm stuck. I've tried using templates for the typecast operators, but I couldn't make them pure virtual:

```cpp
class IBase
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    virtual operator Derived1<T>() = 0; // C2898: 'IBase::operator Derived1<T>(void)': member function templates cannot be virtual

    template <typename T>
    virtual operator Derived2<T>() = 0;
};
```

I've also tried *not* using templates, but the compiler wants a template argument list:

```cpp
class IBase
{
public:
    virtual operator Derived1() = 0;
    virtual operator Derived2() = 0;
};
```

In reality, I have a class `IColor` with children `RGBColor`, `HSVColor`, etc. Is there a way to get this to work? Or is there a better alternative altogether?

Comment: In your real code, what does the template parameter of `RGBColor` indicate?

Comment: @fabian The types of the color components. RGBColor will use `T` for red, green, and blue, and HSVColor will use `T` for hue and `U` for saturation and value

Comment: A template function cannot be virtual because there an infinity of such function so it would t6ake an infinite size v-table and thus a moputer with infinite memory to run that program. Well it might be done otherwise but C++ langage use virtual tables and works that way.

Comment: The whole idea make not much senses at all. If it is predefined types, you don't want arbitrary conversion that might overflow, lost precision... If it is user defined type, then you already need to have conversion available elsewhere. If you really want conversion, then maybe have a named template function such as `As<T>` that would be called `d1.As<Derived2>();`. Even worst is your line `auto d2{ static_cast<Derived2<int>>(d1) };`. Why would want to use cast at the caller site? What is your purpose in writing such code?

Comment: The design is broken. A parent class should not know about its specific children.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. The point is to force the children to all have typecast operators for all other children

Comment: I guess the best you can get here would be to decide on one type to use to store the channel data and provide conversions to other types e.g. `template<typename T>struct RgbColor { T r; ... template<typename U> operator RgbColor<U>() { return RgbColor<U> { convert<U>(r), ... }; } }; struct IColor { virtual RgbColor<int> rgb() = 0; };`

Comment: @fabian That's a good idea that I haven't thought of, thanks :)

Comment: Then perhaps "parents" and "children" is not a good language to achieve this goal. Which is dubious in and of itself by the way. How would you cast from `Derived1<complex<float>>` to `Derived2<string>`? What would such a cast mean?